# Violación de segmento ('core' generado) - Multiplicación de componentes de vectores

Tags: c++, c

he realizado un pequeño programa para multiplicar los componentes del vector y funciona correctamente, pero tras la ejecución me da un error cuando incremento el tamaño del vector.
El objetivo es comparar tiempos de este código en secuencial con un código adaptado a la especificación OpenMP, por lo que me interesa que el tamaño del vector sea muy grande.

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
   // Tamaño del vector.
   const int SIZE = 600000;

   // Vectores a rellenar.
   int v1[SIZE], v2[SIZE];

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      v1[i] = rand()%100;
      v2[i] = rand()%100;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      res[i] = v[i] * v2[i];
   }

}
```

No sé donde está el error, ¿alguien podría ayudarme? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Probablemente sea el tamaño del array 'res'

Comment: Perdona, no he puesto en el código la declaración del array res, pero la línea de código es esta: int res[SIZE]; // Por lo que está correcto.

Comment: Veo que tu código de ejemplo, está escrito en C, deberías de quitar la etiqueta de c++.

Comment: Como dice la respuesta usa memoria dinámica(`malloc` en c, `new` en c++), si el objetivo es solo compararlo con OpenMP, no te hará ningún problemas ya que solo le agregas al `for` el `#pragma omp` y tendrás la comparación con las mismas tareas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablemente esté ocurriendo un [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila).

El [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila) ocurre cuando agregas un tamaño excesivamente grande a un vector o si se hace una recursión infinita.

Tu programa deja de funcionar por esta línea de código:

```
int v1[SIZE], v2[SIZE], res[SIZE];
```

La pila suele ser limitada y por esa razón, se debe tener mucha precaución en no crear un arreglo local con un tamaño muy grande.

La solución en este caso, es usando [memoria dinámica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_din%C3%A1mica_(programaci%C3%B3n)).

```
int main()
{
    // Tamaño del vector.
    const int SIZE = 600000;
    int* v1, *v2, *res;
    //Reservamos memoria para el primer vector
    v1 = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    //Si llega a ver un fallo en la asignación de memoria
    if(v1 == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //Reservamos memoria para el segundo vector
    v2 = malloc(SIZE* sizeof(int));
    //Si llega a ver un fallo en la asignación de memoria
    if(v2 == NULL)
    {
        //Liberamos el vector1 que habíamos reservado anteriormente.
        free(v1);
        return 1;
    }
    //Reservamos memoria para el tercer vector
    res = malloc(SIZE* sizeof(int));
    //Si llega a ver un fallo en la asignación de memoria
    if(res == NULL)
    {
        //Liberamos el vector2 que habíamos reservado anteriormente.
        free(v2);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        v1[i] = rand()%100;
        v2[i] = rand()%100;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        res[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];

    free(v1);
    free(v2);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Al trabajar con memoria dinámica, necesitamos liberar la memoria, para evitar [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria)(pérdida de memoria).

También recalco que el código lo he probado en mi máquina, tiene 2 GB de RAM, por lo tanto, su funcionamiento dependerá de los recursos que tenga tu ordenador.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! ♥